# Wait for FragmentTransaction animation to finish

Tags: android, animation, fragmenttransaction, animator

I have an Activity with an `EditText` and a `Button`. As soon as there is a number entered in the EditText and the Button is clicked, a Fragment (that covers up the whole screen) is being shown for two seconds, and then removed. Both Transactions have `showCustomAnimations()` called. In code, after I call `commit()` on the remove FragmentTransaction, the soft keyboard is shown via `showSoftInput()`.

The problem I face: While the remove animation is running and the Fragment already slid out of the screen by 80%, the softkeyboard pops up. Now if you quickly enter a number and press the button, the app crashes, because the previous animation still was running.

I already saw several answers, but I found them to not be sufficient or working. Any call for `commitNow()` or `executePendingTransitions()` doesn't help, as the Transaction is committed, the problem is, that the animation is still running afterwards. The method `getVisibleUserHint()`to check whether an Activity is visible is deprecated.

Code:

```
TrueFragment trueFragment = new TrueFragment();

fabNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  //fabNext is my button
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            fabNext.setEnabled(false);  //blocking button to avoid clicking (... further code for this...)
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(constraintLayoutCalculating.getWindowToken(), 0);  //hide Keyboard

            final FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();  //FragmentTransaction to show the Fragment
            transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in, 0);
            transaction.add(R.id.constraintLayoutCalculating, trueFragment);
            transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    FragmentTransaction transaction2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();  //FragmentTransaction to remove the Fragment
                    transaction2.setCustomAnimations(0, R.animator.slide_out);
                    transaction2.remove(trueFragment);
                    transaction2.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    editText.setText(null);  //reset EditText
                    editText.requestFocus();
                    textInputLayout.setError(null);
                    inputManager.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);  //show Keyboard
                    fabNext.setEnabled(true);  //reenable button at the end - Problem: Button made clickable again, even if the remove FragmentTransaction animation hasn't finished

               }
         }, 1000);
}
```

This is the crash I am getting. A search on StackOverflow showed me that it has to do with starting a FragmentTransaction while another still isn't finished.

```
 --------- beginning of crash
2020-02-17 10:27:29.787 23467-23467/my.top.secretpreciousname E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    my.top.secretpreciousname, PID: 23467
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Restarter must be created only during owner's initialization stage
        at androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistryController.performRestore(SavedStateRegistryController.java:58)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2585)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:838)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:183)
        at my.top.secretpreciousname.CalculatingActivity$1.onClick(CalculatingActivity.java:254)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7339)
        at my.top.secretpreciousname.CalculatingActivity$2.onEditorAction(CalculatingActivity.java:320)
        at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:8617)
        at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:8486)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:3359)
        at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:13312)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1912)
```

Is there nice solution for this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I have to add the line

```
transaction2.addToBackStack(null);
```

to the animated FragmentTransaction to achieve that it won't crash when a new Transaction is triggered before the previous one has finished its animation.
Still not sure if this can be considered as a valid solution, as actually I don't want backstack functionality with these Fragments, so I have to temporarily block the back button or flush the Backstack after every Transaction.